# Fluent API связь один к одному

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Не получается сделать связь один к одному, ошибка :

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'DataBase.Entities.Branch' and 'DataBase.Entities.Address'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.'

```
public class Branch
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Metro { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CommentToAddress { get; set; }
    public string Schedule { get; set; }
    public string SchedulePrivatePerson { get; set; }
    public string ScheduleGeneral { get; set; }
    public string ScheduleEntities { get; set; }
    public Bank Bank { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CountryCity { get; set; } //город
    public string StreetName { get; set; } // улица
    public string StreetType { get; set; } // "тип" улицы(улица, проспект, проезд) - для оптимизации запроса к карте
    public string ClarifyingAddress { get; set; } //адрес после улицы
    public Branch Branch { get; set; }
}

 public class Bank
{
    public Bank()
    {
        Branches = new HashSet<Branch>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public float DollarBuy { get; set; }
    public float DollarSell { get; set; }
    public float EuroBuy { get; set; }
    public float EuroSell { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime UpdateTime { get; set; }
    public /*virtual*/ ICollection<Branch> Branches { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Configs

```
internal class  AddressConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Address>
{
    public AddressConfig(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        HasKey(p => p.Id);
        Property(p => p.CountryCity).IsRequired();
        Property(p => p.StreetName).IsRequired();
        Property(p => p.StreetType).IsRequired();
        Property(p => p.ClarifyingAddress).IsRequired();
    }
}

internal class BankConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Bank>
{
    internal BankConfig(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        HasKey(p => p.Id);
        Property(p => p.Name).IsRequired();
        Property(p => p.DollarBuy).IsRequired();
        Property(p => p.DollarSell).IsRequired();
        Property(p => p.EuroBuy).IsRequired();
        Property(p => p.EuroSell).IsRequired();
        Property(p => p.UpdateTime).IsRequired().HasColumnType("datetime");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Bank>().HasMany(p => p.Branches).WithRequired(p=>p.Bank);
    }
}

internal class BranchConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Branch>
{
    internal BranchConfig(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        HasKey(p => p.Id);
        Property(p => p.Metro).IsOptional();
        Property(p => p.Name).IsOptional();
        Property(p => p.CommentToAddress).IsOptional();
        Property(p => p.CommentToAddress).IsOptional();
        Property(p => p.SchedulePrivatePerson).IsOptional();
        Property(p => p.ScheduleGeneral).IsOptional();
        Property(p => p.ScheduleEntities).IsOptional();
        Property(p => p.Schedule).IsOptional();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Branch>()
            .HasRequired(p => p.Bank)
            .WithMany(p => p.Branches);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Address>()
            .HasRequired(p => p.Branch)
            .WithRequiredPrincipal(p => p.Address);

    }
}

class CityConfig: EntityTypeConfiguration<City>
{
    public CityConfig()
    {
        HasKey(p => p.Id);
        Property(p => p.Value).IsOptional();
        Property(p => p.Name).IsOptional();
    }
}
```

Context

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context():base("DbMap")
    {
    }

    static Context()
    {
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<Context>(new ContextInitializer());
    }
    public DbSet<Bank> Banks { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Branch> Branches { get; set; }
    public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new BankConfig(modelBuilder));
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new BranchConfig(modelBuilder));
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AddressConfig(modelBuilder));
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CityConfig());

    }
```

ConnectionString

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DbMap"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"
     connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|DbMap1.sdf" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: а где ForeignKey?

Comment: В примерах я не встречал явного указания вторичного ключа, если не трудно, покажите на моем коде

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Что-то вы перемудрили, для того что бы создать связь "**один-к-одному**" достаточно указать:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Address>()
    .HasRequired(p => p.Branch)
    .WithRequiredPrincipal(p => p.Address);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Поправил конфиги:

```
public class AddressConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Address>
{
    public AddressConfig()
    {
        Property(p => p.CountryCity).IsRequired();
        Property(p => p.StreetName).IsRequired();
        Property(p => p.StreetType).IsRequired();
        Property(p => p.ClarifyingAddress).IsRequired();

        HasRequired(p => p.Branch)
           .WithRequiredPrincipal(p => p.Address);
    }
}

public class BankConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Bank>
{
    public BankConfig()
    {
         Property(p => p.Name).IsRequired();
         Property(p => p.DollarBuy).IsRequired();
         Property(p => p.DollarSell).IsRequired();
         Property(p => p.EuroBuy).IsRequired();
         Property(p => p.EuroSell).IsRequired();
         Property(p => p.UpdateTime).IsRequired().HasColumnType("datetime");

         HasMany(p => p.Branches).WithRequired(p => p.Bank);
    }
}

public class BranchConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Branch>
{
    public BranchConfig()
    {
        HasRequired(p => p.Bank)
            .WithMany(p => p.Branches);
    }
}
```

Comment: ошибка осталась, указал всю базу данных в вопросе

Comment: @Jagiello y меня ваш код падает с другой ошибкой.

Comment: Что за ошибка? вот подключенные dll  `<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="HtmlAgilityPack" version="1.5.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact" version="4.0.8876.1" targetFramework="net452" />`

Comment: @Jagiello обновил ответ.

Comment: ээээ, спасибо большое, а из-за чего сейчас работает то? Падало из-за "двухстороннего" объявления  связи с Bank?

Comment: @Jagiello у вас изначально некоторые сущности регистрировались дважды. У меня первоначально по этой причине приложение упало.

Comment: понял, видимо не так понял "уроки", спасибо за потраченное время

Comment: @Jagiello не за что. Обращайтесь.